# Invalid Zip Archive when zipping a pdf document

Tags: c#

I have some documents (pdf and html) as byte arrays. Now I have to create zip archives of those documents. Zipping the HTMLs works without problems but for some reason the zip archives for the pdf documents are all invalid.

I already tried to save just the PDFs without the zip and they work just fine.

Here's my code for creating the Zips:

```cs
byte[] buffer;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        var zipEntry = zip.CreateEntry(document.FileName);
        using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(zipEntry.Open()))
        {
            binaryWriter.Write(document.Content);
        }
    }

    buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing the zip file to a memory stream instead of straight to a file stream? I think you need to flush the writer as not all the bytes have been written to the stream. Also buffer will only contain the last data written to the stream, the buffer is always of a defined constant size.

Comment: Shouldn't you call [`MemoryStream.ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer?view=netframework-4.8) (see Remarks section).

Comment: @Nkosi nope, the problem there was that he copied the stream of the archive before flushing it but i do flush it.

Comment: @orhtej2 Thank you very much. This was the problem.

Comment: Also, why do you use BinaryWriter here? Where did that idea come from? What could possibly prevent you from writing `document.Content` **directly** to the stream provided by `zipEntry.Open()` without making a detour through BinaryWriter?

Comment: @silkfire because the file get's send to a server so no need to save it to disk.

Comment: @elgonzo good question :D don't know why I did it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [orhtej2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7034621/orhtej2) pointed out the `GetBuffer()` Method may return additional bytes. To get the actual buffer you have to use `ToArray()`.

Comment: -1. "_GetBuffer() Method always returns a buffer with a size of 256 bytes._" That is completely false. `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` will NOT always return a buffer with a size of 256 bytes. (It will ever only return a buffer <= 256 in size if the amount of data written to the MemoryStream is less or eqaul 256 bytes)

Comment: hmm then i missunderstood the documentation... but why is my zip broken when using GetBuffer instead of ToArray()?

Comment: Which part of the documentation did you not understand? The documentation for the MemoryStream.GetBuffer method tells you why you possibly have this problem, right there at the start of the Remarks section. The buffer could simply be **larger** than the amount of data written to the MemoryStream. Thus, whatever you use to process/test the ZIP archive might get confused by possible additional and **superfluous** garbage bytes after the end of the ZIP archive and state that the ZIP archive is corrputed/damaged.

Comment: `ToArray` will simply create and return an array that is exactly the size of the data written to the MemoryStream, thus entirely avoiding the possible problem of possible additional garbage bytes after the end of the ZIP archive data.

Comment: alright, I'm sorry it's been a long workday and I'm tired. Now I get it. I corrected the answer.

Comment: still somewhat confusing that it always worked with my html files but not the pdfs ...

Comment: It could be a number of reasons. Considering that HTML data (which is pure text) can be compressed better than a PDF (which might or might not be largely binary, already compressed data), the ZIP compressor algorithm used by ZipArchive might decide on a different compression methods used for the HTML and PDF data. This could perhaps have an coincidental effect where the size of the compressed HTML ZIP archive data just perfectly aligns with the MemoryStream buffer size. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Or, it could also be that whatever you use to test/process the ZIP archives is only sensitive to garbage bytes at the end of a ZIP archive when confronted with ZIP archive entries using some particular compression scheme(s), but not when ZIP archive entries are using other compression schemes. Impossible to know with certainty unless you take a closer look at the HTML ZIP archives with a hex editor (and knowing or having the ZIP file format specification at hand, of course) and look whether they have additional superfluous garbage bytes...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save that bytes to a file, or return them in a kind of API, you can use the stream as a source for that operation.

If you want to save to a file in disk, use `Stream.CopyTo` passing a new `FileStream`. If you want to return thoose bytes in a WebAPI create a `StreamContent` and return it.

`GetBuffer` will return the stream underlying buffer which eventually will contains unused bytes. `ToArray` will create an additional unnecessary `byte[]`.

Comment: Note that before using `Stream.CopyTo` to dump the MemoryStream content into another (File)Stream, you would need to reset the MemoryStream read/write position back to the beginning of the MemoryStream (`memoryStream.Position = 0`). Otherwise, nothing will be copied because the read/write position of the MemoryStream is and remains **behind** the written data. (Another option avoidng CopyTo would be to simply provide that other (File)Stream directly to ZipArchive)